# Conditions in Alfresco policies binding

Tags: alfresco

I have OnCreateNodePolicy implementation and I'm thinking about adding conditions in binding initialization (some optimalizations for speed), is it possible?
What do I mean? Let's have definition similar to this:

```
policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
    QName.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onCreateNode"),
    ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, onCreateNode);
```

Now when node is created, mine onCreateNode() is called. First thing I do is to check, if my parent has some aspect. Isn't it possible to add this condition into binding definition? So onCreateNode() is called only when this condition is met?

Comment: Something somewhere will still have to do the check though, won't it?

Comment: Yes, it will, but in many cases that check will not be reached ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not add conditions to the binding definition but in your case you could consider using the `OnCreateChildAssociationPolicy` instead of the `OnCreateNodePolicy`. The advantage is that you could bind it to your custom aspect. It would look something like this:

```
policyComponent.bindAssociationBehaviour(
        NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateChildAssociationPolicy.QNAME,
        YourCustomModel.ASPECT_YOURASPECT, 
        ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, 
        new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateChildAssociation", NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT)
);
```

You have to keep in mind though that child associations are also created when you move a node to a new folder, not only when you create it. Also you now have to check the type of the child node (`ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT`) in your Java code.

Comment: sounds good, i'll try it in free time, I've deployed previous version for now